# Trigger onChange when setting State in componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to add some query paramaters to my url as a person checks off checkboxes.

I am using react router so I do something like this in my checkboxes on change event.

```
  const stringified = queryString.stringify(parsed);
  const path = `${this.props.location.pathname}?${stringified}`;
  this.props.history.replace(path)
```

This does however seem to cause a re-render of the page(not sure if this should be happening, would prefer it not to do that so maybe I got to use something other than replace?).

I wanted to check on componentDidMount the url to see if the value is there. If it is there then I wanted to update the state of the checkbox.

```
  @observable
  isChecked = false;

  @action
  componentDidMount() {
    const parsed = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    this.isChecked = parsed && parsed["param"] === this.props.option;
  }
```

However I don't see the onChange being trigger.

Right now I have on change a function that takes the value and uses it to filter, so I need the function to run.

I could put that function in the componentDidMount but I wanted to make sure before I do that, there is nothing I am missing on why the change event is not be fired.

Comment: Would it make more sense/make this problem a non-issue to have the component respond to the URL rather than the URL respond to the component?  eg on mount you check the URL (maybe not directly but via some higher level controller) and set the checkbox, and on checkbox change you update the URL and allow that to trickle down to the component? (I think I'm oversimplifying how I'm thinking it could work but hopefully you get the gist of my idea)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the state in the `constructor()` and in`componentDidUpdate()`.

When a URL parameter is added to the same route, the existing component is utilized (i.e. an update event) vs. a new one being created. As a result, you won't see a `componentDidMount()` event.

Another option/solution is to update the state of `isChecked` directly and push the history/url change.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to prevent is the page refresh use this built in function in your onSubmit event(if I understand your question correctly.)

```
event.preventDefault();
```

It stops the browser from auto-refreshing! Make sure to call event in your function though.
ie

```
onSubmit=(event)=>{
event.preventDefault();
//rest of code
}
```

If you are trying to filter, the es6 .filter method is useful for checkboxes. I personally used a select dropdown menu to filter the options and selectively show the ticked items in a ToDo List: "Done" "Active" "Completed" and used those states in my filter method.